# fcm onNotification not called when app not active

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angular7, ionic4

I have a problem in `fcm.onNotification`. But in my case, I get the notifications when the app is in background, as I would expect.

But when I tap on the notification the onNotification handler is not called(app is opening but no response from onNotification). When the app is active, the onNotification handler is called.

**INFO:-** Previously I have issue in fcm plugin so I did some changes in plugin :

in --> */plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/src/android/FCMPlugin.gradle*

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
```

and -->  */platforms/android/project.properties*

```
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2
```

My Code in app.component.ts

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
     console.log(JSON.stringify(this.fcm));
     if(data.wasTapped){
        console.log("Received in background data.wasTapped");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
     } else {
          console.log("Received in foreground");
     };
  });
```

Payload sending by using firebase cloud functions:

```
dataString = '{"to": "'+token+'","notification":{"title":"Message","body":"From '+eId+'","sound":"default"},"data":{"notificationKey":"'+ key +'","goto":"messageForBidder","evid":"'+eventId+'","id":"'+id+'"},"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY","icon":"fcm_push_icon"}';
```